# Parsing JSON With changeable key

Tags: php, json, parsing

I try to parse json variables with php codes. Problem is some of array keys contain changeable values for each iteration. By the way this is not a duplicate question, there is nothing like json parsing with changeable variables. Here is my json example and php codes and also output;

```
{
    "link":"",
    "host":"stream",
    "filename":"Rock Ballads The Best Of 70-90's",
    "icon":"https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/JN80ayCfmW0\/hqdefault.jpg",
    "streaming":{
        "audio track in mp3 (54.54MB)":"http:\/\/server.example.parsing.com\/str\/wlqcjv8246\/Rock+Ballads+The+Best+Of+70-90%26%23039%3Bs%28p%29.mp3",
        "360p video in mp4 (80.04MB)":"http:\/\/server.example.parsing.com\/str\/wlqcjyfc33\/Rock+Ballads+The+Best+Of+70-90%26%23039%3Bs%28480p%29.mp4",
        "240p video in mp4 (76.55MB)":"http:\/\/server.example.parsing.com\/str\/wlqck18b72\/Rock+Ballads+The+Best+Of+70-90%26%23039%3Bs%28240p%29.mp4",
        "144p video in mp4 (71.09MB)":"http:\/\/server.example.parsing.com\/str\/wlqck4e410\/Rock+Ballads+The+Best+Of+70-90%26%23039%3Bs%28144p%29.mp4"
    },
    "nb":0,
    "error":"",
    "paws":false
}
```

and this is the php code that I use;

```
if($host=="www.youtube.com"){
    $decodeProcess = json_decode($output,true);
    echo ($decodeProcess['filename']);
    echo ($decodeProcess['icon']);
    echo ($decodeProcess['streaming']['audio track in mp3 (54.54MB)']);

}
```

In this case filename and icon works well but "audio track in mp3 (54.54MB)" or "144p video in mp4 (71.09MB)" is problem for me to parse because everytime the file size changes. What can I do?

Comment: Just to clarify, your variable `$host` is from the json key `"host"`?

Comment: Where are you getting this JSON from?  One solution could be to loop over `$decodeProcess['streaming']` and see if the key contains `audio track in mp3` or whatever.

Comment: if that's the case, then you want to parse the json and assign `$host` to the content of `someJson->host`

Comment: @Kai no, it is for defining the if statement it is not related with it

Comment: Ouch, that's an awful key.

Comment: You need to define the problem better. Do you always want the 1st item in the streaming array? Or perhaps the 1st one containing `audio` in the key? Maybe you want to access all the results?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm triying to find a solution but there is nothing for now

Comment: @Steve I want to access all the result ofcourse

Comment: `"ofcourse"` ... If that was obvious i would not have asked. Then you can simple loop over the results: `foreach($decodeProcess['streaming'] as $item) echo $item;`

Comment: Use `foreach ($decodeProcess['streaming'] as $size => $url)` to loop over all of the tracks.

Comment: @Barmar and how can i declare a variable with this result. I don't want to print, i want to use these in other parts

Comment: Push them onto an array.

Comment: Can you change that JSON format?

Comment: @MikeBrant I wish, but i take it from remote server which is not mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered running a simple mapping operation on the data structure to get it into a more workable form (basically dropping file size information from keys)?

That might look like:

```
if($host=="www.youtube.com"){
    $decodeProcess = json_decode($output,true);
    // array of prefix matches that will be used as as substitution keys
    $key_replacements = [
        'audio' => 'audio',
        '360p video' => 'video_360p',
        '240p video' => 'video_240p',
        '144p video' => 'video_144p'
    ];
    foreach($decodeProcess['streaming'] as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($key_replacements as $prefix => $replacement) {
            if (strpos($key, $prefix) === 0) {
                $decodeProcess['streaming'][$replacement] = $value;
                break;
            }
        }
        unset($decodeProces['streaming'][$key]);
    }

    echo ($decodeProcess['filename']);
    echo ($decodeProcess['icon']);
    echo ($decodeProcess['streaming']['audio']);
    echo ($decodeProcess['streaming']['video_360p']);
}
```

Of course you might want to then encapsulate the overall JSON deserialization and key mapping functionality into its own function or class method.

Comment: @AlperenÖzdemir Sorry. Had left out my commas in `$key+replacements` array definition :P.  Fixed.